# Hudson kills the process at end of the shell script

Tags: deployment, shell-scripting, hudson

Im configuring Hudson to automate deployment process. In shell script I start the server using different user and Im able to see the logs which says server is successfully started and able to access the application. But Once Hudson reaches end of the script the process killed.

When I check process details, till the shell script complete, the process alive. Once the shell script is complete the process is not there.

Can you please help me how to keep the process alive even after shell script execution is completed by Hudson

Resolved by the trick mentioned in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5728899/tomcat-script-not-working-when-run-from-hudson

Comment: Resolved by the trick mentioned in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5728899/tomcat-script-not-working-when-run-from-hudson

Answer (score 0):

Can you provide the script?

Have you tried simply appending & to the server start command to background it?

Comment: Thanks !!! I tried with nohup but no luck, Resolved this issue by solution given in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5728899/tomcat-script-not-working-when-run-from-hudson